# Enabling MMU in Linux

Tags: linux, arm, mmu

1. In ARM Linux , at exactly which point mmu is enabled. ie , in which file (assembly file or paging_init() in arch/arm/kernel/setup.c)
2. Does ARM linux have support to run without paging.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at [this](http://amitshah.bizhat.com/arm/arm_linux_boot-1.html)(dead) and [this](https://jsevy.com/linux/ARM_Linux_boot_sequence.html) pages on ARM Linux booting process. They're probably somewhat out of date but should be pretty close.

1. MMU gets enabled in [arch/arm/kernel/head.S](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19/source/arch/arm/kernel/head.S#L449), in `__enable_mmu` function.
2. You can even run without MMU at all; uCLinux project has been merged into mainline a couple years ago.

Comment: Links are dead :(.

Comment: @pevik thanks, found a copy of the second one; for the first you can use archive.org

Answer (score 2):

Actually if you are working on embedded system using Linux on ARM systems, then generally in the bootloader there is no MMU and when bootloader switches to Kernel then in [arch/arm/boot/compressed/head.S](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19/source/arch/arm/boot/compressed/head.S#L696), we set up MMU in `__setup_mmu` function.

First page tables are created which are used for page translation and then we start with MMU setup.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer to the first question offhand.  I would have browse sources.

The ELDK I am using on a custom ARM board does not have paging, and Linux works just fine.